# iOS 6.1.2 - Why the UIAlertView not be dismissed? background still on the screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6, uialertview

here is my code:

```
UIAlertView *someError = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:@"Server Error!" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle: @"ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];
[someError show];
```

when I tap the ok button,the alert background still there,and I tap the screen,the status bar is flickering.

I found some answers,but they not work,I changed my code to:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
       UIAlertView *someError = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:@"Server Error!" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle: @"ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];
       [someError show];
});
```

or set the Delegate:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
       UIAlertView *someError = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:@"Server Error!" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle: @"ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];
       [someError show];
});

-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [alertView dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:buttonIndex animated:NO];
    });

}
```

it still not work,then I try to:

```
UIAlertView *someError = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:@"error" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle: @"ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];
[someError performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(show) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
```

not work,crazy,this is not work too:

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(showAlert:) withObject:@"error", nil)  waitUntilDone:NO];

// the show Alert function
-(void)showAlert:(NSString*)str
{
    UIAlertView *someError = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message: str delegate: nil cancelButtonTitle: @"ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [someError performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(show) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
}
```

still not work.

before and after alert show:

[image: before the alert show]  [image: after tap ok]

Answer (score 3):

Make certain your view controller (or wherever you are creating your UIAlertView from) has "`<UIAlertViewDelegate>`" defined in the @interface line.  For example:

```
@interface YellowViewController : UIViewController <UIAlertViewDelegate>
```

Now, when you create a UIAlertView from your subclassed view controller and set the delegate to self, your view controller *should* conform to and *should* receive the delegate protocol methods.

Next thing.  This bit of code looks correct to me:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
       UIAlertView *someError = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:@"Server Error!" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle: @"ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];
       [someError show];
});
```

But your delegate method calls are going to happen on the main thread (which is where all the UI happens):

```
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    [alertView dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:buttonIndex YES];
}
```

In other words, get rid of the dispatch stuff in there and see what happens.  Then again, [the Apple documentation for "`clickedButtonAtIndex:`" says](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertViewDelegate_Protocol/UIAlertViewDelegate/UIAlertViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIAlertViewDelegate/alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex:):

> **Discussion**
>
> The receiver is automatically dismissed after this method
> is invoked.

So you might not need to actually explicitly dismiss the alert view.

Comment: I has tried,but not work too,the alert box is dismissed,but the black background still on the screen like the screenshot.I have NSLog in alertView delegate,it has been called. How can I remove the background  by manual?

Comment: Hmmmm... if this delegate method is in your view controller, try "`[self becomeFirstResponder];`" after you dismiss your alert.

Comment: Michael Dautermann ,it still not work...can I don't show the background when alert popup?

Answer (score 1):

All the UIKit stuff must work in the main thread, make sure your alertView are called in main thread. Also, the **view that show your alert must be in main thread**.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution for this or rather the problem for which this scenario occurs. Well i am late but I am sure you must be using some external libraries to show progress such as "SVProgressHUD" or "MBProgressHUD". These libraries play great amount with that of the main WINDOW hierarchy which in result causes problems for native UI elements such as UIAlertView or rather Picker Controller etc. The only escape to this problem is try not using the third party library that I named above if any. Everything works fine then. It was a head breaking silly thing for me also.

Answer (score 0):

Well I was suffering the same thing. I tried everything but didn't work. Here's what has worked for me, hopefully you'll find it helpful too.

Write a UIAlertView delegate method and put a breakpoint in it.

```
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
```

Now resume and you will notice the dim effect has gone. So just put a delay of say 0.5s in this delegate and hopefully your problem is solved. Well it's worked for me

Write a UIAlertView delegate method and put a breakpoint in it.

```
[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.5];
```